# Fetch last argument of csh source command

Tags: csh

say I try following in csh:

1. `source script.csh a b c d`
2. `source script.csh a s j`
3. `source script.csh a k h s p`

I need to get the last argument passed with number of parameters varying per source'ing, Example for `d` for 1, `j` for 2, and `p` for 3. How do I do it in csh?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following I tried worked:

```
set arg_count = $#

set sim = "$argv[$arg_count]"
```